# C++ : Base type member variables as References, or Pointer

Tags: c++, inheritance, class-members

I am wondering what might be the best way to accomplish a design dilemma in C++ ...

I have a class, which contains member variables of type `Base` of another class, and the real objects that are created are created as `Derived` of `Base`.

The class does not need to modify these variables, it is only using them. Someone else is creating these variables. These `Derived` classes also need to go to container (std::vector, QList, etc) classes in my class, so they should perform proper copy construction and assignment.

So, I was wondering what might be the best:

1. Create the member variables as a `Base*` and let us manage them and the memory they use. This leads to the classical memory leak issues... Someone just forgets to delete the object when they are not using it anymore.
2. Create the member variables as a `Base&` and let's pray that they do not disappear when they go out of scope somewhere.

Comment: The best way to do that (and everything else) is to be always careful in allocating and deallocating variables.

Comment: "Someone just forgets to delete the object" -- no, if "we" (this class) is managing the memory, then "someone" doesn't forget to delete the object, *we* forget to delete the object. There should never be an issue of "remembering" to delete something -- whenever you allocate an object, you decide who is responsible for freeing it. That class/function/whatever ensures it's freed, and you write the code to do so immediately. Almost always by putting it straight into a smart pointer. Don't get into a vague idea of "someone has to free this" in the first place, and you won't fail to free it.

Answer (score 1):

Having reference member variables is always a poor choice because the compiler generated assignment and move assignment do the wrong thing, or not what one would expect.

Stick to pointers or smart pointers for member variables.

Comment: I had thought those simply weren't generated for you - in VC 2010, I get a warning for it, but no error. g++ 4.7 gives me no warning, except when I try to use the assignment operator:  error: use of deleted function 'ref_test& ref_test::operator=(co
nst ref_test&)'

Comment: Just tried with gcc-4.7.1 and it does indeed generate an error in both C+98 and C++11 modes. It didn't in the past if my memory serves me right.

Answer (score 1):

@hansmaad is just right, if you have a problem in controlling life time of the object you should share its ownership with those who create or manage it.
You have 2 options:
 1) `boost::shared_ptr` or `std::tr1::shared_ptr`
    You can easily use this class for any type `Base` without changing `Base`, but if you are working in a multi threaded environment it is very hard to achieve thread safety for `shared_ptr` and do not forget if you create an object as shared using one of this classes you should not manage the life time of the object directly and it is not legal to create a new shared object from raw pointer and you should always copy construct shared object. for example:

```
boost::shared_ptr<Base> sharedObject( new Drived() );
boost::shared_ptr<Base> validCopy( sharedObject );    // Ok share ownership
Base* p = sharedObject.get();
boost::shared_ptr<Base> invalidCopy( p );    // Error, can't create new shared_ptr from raw pointer
```

2) `boost::intrusive_ptr`
    You can easily make it thread safe and you can pass it as either raw pointer or smart pointer since it can constructed from raw pointer because reference counting is implemented in the class instead but you should change definition of the class and add you reference counting mechanism

Answer (score 0):

You should think about ownership. Whe owns that objects? If there is no clear answer to this questions, you should use a `std::shared_ptr<Base>` (shared ownership). If there is one class that owns that objects and all others just use them, you could use a `std::unique_ptr<Base>`, a pointer container like `boost::ptr_vector` or if there is no polymorphism it that owning classes just the concrete instance. In all other classes you can use plain pointers (prefered as class members) or references (prefered as arguments, if null is not allowed) to that objects.

Case 1 - Shared ownership

```
class IWorkOnBaseObjects
{
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Base>> mySubset;
};

class MeToo
{
    std::shared_ptr<Base> iNeedThisOne;
};
```

Case 2

```
class HomeOfBaseObjects
{
    std::vector<std::uniqe_ptr<Base>> baseObjects;
};

class IWorkOnBaseObjects
{
    std::vector<Base*> mySubset;
};
```

Case 3

```
class A : public Base{};
class B : public Base{};

class HomeOfAObjects
{
    std::vector<A> aObjects;
};

class HomeOfBObjects
{
    std::vector<B> bObjects;
};

class INeedABaseObject
{
    Base* thisOne;
};
```

Comment: "If you can't answer this questions, you should ..." put C++ down, back slowly away, and come back when you can answer it ;-) Shared ownership shouldn't be a default "I don't know" position, it should be a positive answer to the question. Otherwise you'll get into trouble eventually, and you will come up with some ad hoc mixture of shared and weak pointers to avoid reference loops. Then you'll lose track of that and get into more trouble.

Comment: @SteveJessop There are (rare) situations where there is no clear answer. I didn't mean it like "arghh don't know.. lets take a shared_ptr"

Comment: Yep, I figured you didn't mean that, but my fear is that someone would read it that way! "You" in my comment really meant "you the reader who does that", not "you, hansmaad" :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would go with pointers, both for your vectors (i.e., `vector<Base *>`, not `vector<Base>`) and your container class for the following reasons:

- If you store the Derived objects in a vector, that vector may get re-sized, which causes all the objects to 'move' to new locations in memory. This would invalidate all outstanding pointers and references
- If your container contains references, you are not able to copy it as easily as you would if it contains pointers, as references can only be bound when defined (so in the constructor via `MyClass::MyClass(int &a) : memberA(a) {}`, if memory serves)
- Pointers can be changed via other means such as set methods as needed, and can be set to null in the event of an absence of information

As far as ownership goes, jrok was the first to say it: `shared_ptr<>` is your friend. Don't reinvent the wheel, just make use of the standard library to simplify things for you. The only thing you would need to worry about in that case is circular pointers (i.e., the object points to itself, so there is always a valid pointer).

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to consider with reference member variables is whether your class (not `Derived`, the class that's going to have a data member that is a pointer or a reference to `Base`) needs value semantics (which is another way of saying, "copies and assigns properly").

If so, then reference member variables are more or less out of the question straight away, because they can't be reseated. There are some odd situations where you can use them anyway, but you might as well assume that you won't, and use pointers.

Reference data members are occasionally useful for types that have "entity semantics" (that is, they don't assign at all and may or may not copy), but still they don't gain you a great deal. They can also lure you into the error of writing a constructor that takes a `const Base&` parameter, and storing it in a reference data member[*].

Who owns the object (and is responsible for freeing it) is completely independent of whether you use a pointer or a reference. There's probably a general convention not to use references for things you own (and there *should* be a convention not to use raw pointers for things you own, you should choose or write a suitable smart pointer. Smart pointer classes can hold a raw pointer). But that is just convention. You shouldn't assume that you manage the memory if and only if you have a pointer.

Summary: use a pointer, then make a separate decision how the memory is managed.

[*] This is a mistake, because eventually someone will accidentally use a temporary object in an initializer, and then the instance of your class with its reference data member will outlive the temporary. For this reason, things that store references for use after they return shouldn't take `const &` parameters, even if they don't modify the object. They can take `const *` instead. In C++11 I suppose they might be OK if there is also an rvalue reference overload, to prevent the `const&` overload being selected for temporaries, but it's not something I've tried out yet.